# Magento 2 Mass Delete Cannot read property 'total' of undefined

Tags: magento2, massaction, console, ui-grid, undefine

I tried to perform mass delete on my custom UI grid but it gives me error in console "Cannot read property 'total' of undefined" i don't understand whats wrong with my code, my gride code is given below

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">

                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Post</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters" />
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
        <exportButton name="export_button"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="spinner_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
```

In console it gives me error like
[image]